# Syntax Error When Writing Data Into a Table - unexpected T_VARIABLE

Tags: php, insert, syntax-error

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in upload_file.php on line 44

The code worked until I added these lines :

Lines 42-44 :

```
$path = "uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
$Link = mysql_connect($Host, $User, $Password);
$Query = "INSERT INTO $Table_7 VALUES ('0','"$path"')";
```

Thanks it sorta worked. The script is for uploading images into a folder. That part of works but I cannot write the image path into the table. I have a table with two fields :

```
picid - auto incrementing primary key
path - varchar(60)
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? I've added the full script.

UPDATE. FULL CODE

```
<?php
include "connect.php";
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 10000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

    if (file_exists("uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
$path = "uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
$Link = mysql_connect($Host, $User, $Password);
$Query = "INSERT INTO $Table_7 VALUES ('0','{$path}')";
?>
```

Comment: I'm gonna just upload a file called `Robert'); DROP TABLE Students; --`...

Comment: ... `$Table_6` will still exist, right? "Party of four, for Table 6, right this way please; yes it's still available for this evening".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing you concatenation operator on line 44:

```
$Query = "INSERT INTO $Table_7 VALUES ('0','"$path"')";
```

should be

```
$Query = "INSERT INTO $Table_7 VALUES ('0','".$path."')";
```

or

```
$Query = "INSERT INTO $Table_7 VALUES ('0','$path')";
```

or

```
$Query = "INSERT INTO $Table_7 VALUES ('0','{$path}')";
```

Comment: I'm no longer getting syntax errors but the data is not being written into the table. Any ideas?

Comment: Then try adding `if (mysql_query($Query, $Link)) { echo ("Database query successful"); }else { die ("Database query failed: " .mysql_error()); }` after `$Query = "INSERT INTO $Table_7 VALUES ('0','{$path}')";` @Nullbreaker

Comment: You're welcome. Did it solve your problem? @Nullbreaker

Comment: If it has, just click the `White Checkmark` next to John's answer till it turns `Green` in order to properly "close" the question. @Nullbreaker